# How to implement simple javascript touch events for webkit on WebOS while developing web content

Tags: webkit, webos

did anyone come across difficulties while trying to implement simple js touch events for webkit and found a solution for it ?

Basically my touch start, touch move, and touch end events are not being detected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Palm webOS's webkit doesn't implement touch events at this time.  Instead, the system sends gesture events.  These aren't super well documented, but they are used in the mojomatters sample code that's part of the Palm webOS SDK.  Look at the gesture-assistant.js source file for gestureStart, gestureChange, and gestureEnd.

Comment: Hello,

thanks for your reply. I was rather talking about the browser app itselt and not the SDK...